# Rank multiple queries against one document based on relevance

Tags: information-retrieval

Given a list of queries and given **one** document, I want to rank the queries based on how relevant they are to the given document.

For each query, I calculated the term frequency of each word in the query. 
(term frequency defined as the number of times the word occurs in the document divided by the total number of words in the document)

Now, I summed up the term frequencies for each term in the query.

For example:

```
search query: "Hello World"
document: "It is a beautiful world"

tf for 'Hello': 0
tf for 'World': 1/5 = 0.2

total tf for query 'Hello World' = 0 + 0.2 = 0.2
```

My question is, what is the best way to normalize my term frequency for each query? so that a long query doesn't result in a larger relevance score.

And, is there a better way for me to score the query than just using the tf score?

I can't use tf-idf in my scenario because I am ranking them against just one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your question, I want to correct you on your definition of term frequency. The way you defined term frequency is actually called [maximum likelihood](http://www.randomservices.org/random/point/Likelihood.html).

So, I am interpreting your first question as follows.

> What is the best way to normalize final score (summation of maximum likelihood) for each query?

One simple approach is to divide the score by query length so that longer query doesn't receive higher score. Advanced techniques are also used in computing relevance score in the context of search engines.

> Is there a better way for me to score the query than just using the tf score?

Yes, of course! One of the well-known and widely used ranking method called [Okapi BM25](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) can be used here with little modification. You can think your target task as a ranking problem.

So, given a document, rank a set of queries based on their relevance with the document.

This is a well-known problem in the context of search engine. I encourage you to follow some lectures from any information retrieval class of any university. For example, this [lecture slide](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~hw5x/Course/IR2015/_site/docs/PDFs/Probabilistic%20Ranking%20Principle.pdf) talks about probabilistic ranking principle which aligns with your need.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to your remark on not being able to use idf, '**I can't use tf-idf in my scenario because I am ranking them against just one document.**', here's what you could do:

Keep in mind that your ranking (retrievable) units are queries. Hence, consider that there's a reversal of roles between documents and queries with reference to the standard terminology.
In other words, treat your queries as pseudo-documents and your document as the pseudo-query.

You can then apply a whole range of ranking models that make use of the collection statistics (being computed over the set of queries), e.g. language model, BM25, DFR etc.